# Multisite Sub-domain creation Doubt | what will be the document root folder?

Tags: multisite

After all, I am finally able to create a multisite on my domain [here](http://bollywoodhatke.com/).

I created a subdomain of that [multisite](http://pictures.bollywoodhatke.com/) See the image →[image]

but the site is hosted on the HostGator, and the sub-domain was not already created, but while creating the sub domain I came across a situation where I got confused the HostGator is asking for the document root? what document root should I give since the sub-domain has already been created so I guess the multi site WordPress has created a root. isn't IT?[image]

I think since in multi site the database is same so the root should be the same of the primary or the first site?

Please guide me.

Comment: Yes, the document root should be the same as your main domain. Isn't this something you can easily test by just using the same document root and seeing if it works?

Comment: sure, let me check this and then I will let you know. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated the document root for → http://pictures.bollywoodhatke.com/ but still the subdomain doesn't seems to be working → https://www.screencast.com/t/jXnxWfqylC2B